# Resolve mutual left recursive grammar

Tags: vba, parsing, grammar, antlr4

### Problem

I'm working on a [grammar](https://github.com/rossknudsen/Vba.Language) for the VBA language based on the [Microsoft specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx) using Antlr4. I've tried to stick closely to the grammar specification, but have one mutual left recursion error to resolve due to this.  Here is a subset of the full grammar which shows the problem:

```
lExpression
    :   simpleNameExpression
    |   Me //instanceExpression 5.6.11
    |   memberAccessExpression
    |   indexExpression
    |   dictionaryAccessExpression
    |   withExpression
    ;

memberAccessExpression      :   lExpression '.' unrestrictedName;

indexExpression             :   lExpression '(' argumentList ')';

dictionaryAccessExpression  :   lExpression '!' unrestrictedName;
```

I could move the sub-expressions into the main `lExpression` rule to overcome the initial problem but I will cause problems in other rules such as the following:

```
callStatement               
    :   Call? (simpleNameExpression | memberAccessExpression | indexExpression | withExpression);
```

Which identifies specific sub-expressions which are permitted in the rule.  There are other places where this occurs also, I just chose this one as an example.

### Idea 1

Write `callStatement` like this:

```
callStatement               
    :   Call? lExpression;
```

Then find a way to disable `lExpression` in `callStatement` from being `Me` or `dictionaryAccessExpression`.

### Idea 2

Write `callStatement` like this:

```
callStatement               
    :   Call? (simpleNameExpression | lExpression '.' unrestrictedName | lExpression '(' argumentList ')' | withExpression);
```

But I'm not sure that Antlr will like that anyway.

### Thoughts

I may be able to use semantic predicates and/or rewrites to improve this but I'm pretty green in this area.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just leave `memberAccessExpression`, `indexExpression` and `dictionaryAccessExpression` as they are, so that `callStatement` can use them, end expand these rules inside `lExpression`:

```
lExpression
    :   simpleNameExpression
    |   Me //instanceExpression 5.6.11
    |   lExpression '.' unrestrictedName
    |   lExpression '(' argumentList ')'
    |   lExpression '!' unrestrictedName
    |   withExpression
    ;

memberAccessExpression      :   lExpression '.' unrestrictedName;

indexExpression             :   lExpression '(' argumentList ')';

dictionaryAccessExpression  :   lExpression '!' unrestrictedName;

callStatement
    :   Call? (simpleNameExpression | memberAccessExpression | indexExpression | withExpression)
    ;
```

> [...] Is it possible to use a rewrite rule in lExpression to add the memberAccessExpression etc nodes to the parse tree?

Alas, v4 does not support rewrite rules. However, you can use [rule labels](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules#ParserRules-AlternativeLabels) so inside your listener or visitor it is clear in which alternative you are:

```
lExpression
    :   simpleNameExpression               #SimpleNameExpressionAlt
    |   Me                                 #MeExpressionAlt
    |   lExpression '.' unrestrictedName   #MemberAccessExpressionAlt
    |   lExpression '(' argumentList ')'   #IndexExpressionAlt
    |   lExpression '!' unrestrictedName   #DictionaryAccessExpressionAlt
    |   withExpression                     #WithExpressionAlt
    ;
```

And inside a listener you would then override `enterMemberAccessExpressionAlt`:

```
public class YourListener extends YourBaseListener {

  @Override
  public void enterMemberAccessExpressionAlt(YourParser.MemberAccessExpressionAltContext ctx) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, not sure how I missed that obvious solution...  Is it possible to use a rewrite rule in `lExpression` to add the `memberAccessExpression` etc nodes to the parse tree?

Comment: Hey, that's cool.  I still have to get my head around how I'm going to use Listeners/Visitors effectively.  No doubt I'll have more questions when I get to that stage!